# Spring Boot - will the executable jar be exploded in after deployment?

Tags: spring-boot

From the documentation of Spring Boot, I can see the directory of the executable jar will be the working directory when you start the Spring Boot application. I would like to understand, whether there are configurations/flags to explode/unpack the jar on deployment, so that I can find access the contents of the executable jar in the file system ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are not flags to explode the jar automatically but you can extract it yourself using the jar command.  This reference may be helpful http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html in understanding the structure and what you can do.